# Value of a car is given by V=18000(0.85)^t (t is years after purchase). Use definite integral to find the average value over the first 6 years.

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

I missed this question on my math quiz can someone explain what I did wrong?

(A) The value V(dollars) of a car is given by V=18,000(0.85)^t, t being number of years after it was purchased. I need to use definite integral to write an expression that can be used to find the average value of the car over the first 6 years.

My definite integral is

$$
\int_0^6 18000(0.85)^tln(0.85)dx
$$

To my understanding I chose the derivative of V as it is dollars/time
The second part to my question is: Use the RHS and LHS with 12 subintervals to approximate the definite integral in part(a), then use it to approximate the average value of the car over the first 6 years.

For this part I find the LHS and RHS of my integral being -11672.99 and -10761.96. I then average out the two to get an approximate -11208.22. I add this to the original value of the car being $18,000 and get $6791.78. Which I can check that this is correct as it is close to 18,000(0.85)^6.

However my teachers answer was
A: $$\frac16\int_0^6 18000(0.85)^t$$
B: 1/6((LHS+RHS)/2)=$11504.25

Answer (score 1):

You need to utilize the mean value theorem for the first part: the average value of an integrable function $f$ over $(a,b)$ is given by

$$\frac{1}{b-a} \int_a^b f(x)dx$$

$V$ is your $f$ here: I'm not sure why you would use the derivative.